# Counting argument for an alternating sum identity $\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}f(a,b,c)=(-1)^{a+c}\binom{a-1}{c-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

Let $f(a,b,c)$ be the number of ways of writing a set of size $a$ as a union of $b$ distinct subsets of size $c$. I've noticed that
$$\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}f(a,b,c)=(-1)^{a+c}\binom{a-1}{c-1}\tag{*}$$
This can be proved as follows. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2039864/181986), $f$ is given by
$$f(a,b,c) = \sum_{i=0}^a(-1)^i\binom{a}{i}\binom{\binom{a-i}{c}}{b}$$
Then,
$$\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}f(a,b,c)=\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}\sum_{i=0}^{a}(-1)^i\binom{a}{i}\binom{\binom{a-i}{c}}{b} = \sum_{i=0}^{a}(-1)^i\binom{a}{i}\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}\binom{\binom{a-i}{c}}{b}. \tag{**}$$

Now by the binomial theorem,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=\begin{cases}0 & n > 0\\ 
1 & n =0
\end{cases}.$$
Using this identity and the fact that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ for $k>n$, the inner sum of $(**)$ can be written as
$$\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}\binom{\binom{a-i}{c}}{b}=\begin{cases}
            0 & i\leq a-c\\ 
            -1 & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}.$$
Substituting into $(**)$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{a}(-1)^i\binom{a}{i}\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b+1}\binom{\binom{a-i}{c}}{b} = \sum_{i=a-c+1}^{a}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{a}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{c-1}(-1)^{i+a+1}\binom{a}{i}.$$
Lastly, using the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums) for alternating partial sums of a row in pascal's triangle,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{c-1}(-1)^{i+a+1}\binom{a}{i}=(-1)^{a+c}\binom{a-1}{c-1}.$$

This clean closed form makes me wonder if there is a simpler way of proving $(*)$. In particular, is there a simple counting argument that can prove $(*)$ without computing $f(a,b,c)$?

The alternating nature of the sum in $(*)$ suggests it may be a form of the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I have not been able to model it as such.

**EDIT**

One potential way forward is to use ideas from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425732/159124). Fix $a$ and $c$. Let $\mathcal{R}=\{S\subseteq[a]:|S|=c\}$. Let $I:\mathcal{P}([a])\rightarrow \mathcal{P}([a])$ be the indicator function for covers of $[a]$. Then,
$$\sum_{b=0}^{\binom{a}{c}}(-1)^{b}f(a,b,c)=\sum_{\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{R}}(-1)^{|\mathcal{S}|}I(\mathcal{S})$$
so it would remain to show that the RHS is $(-1)^{a+c+1}\binom{a-1}{c-1}$. The form on the RHS is also promising because it resembles the mobius inversion of $I$ on the boolean lattice $B_a$. In particular, if we define
$$g(\mathcal{T})=\sum_{\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{T}}(-1)^{|\mathcal{T}|-|\mathcal{S}|}I(\mathcal{S})$$
then $g$ is the mobius inversion of $I$, or equivalently,
$$I(\mathcal{T}) = \sum_{\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{T}}g(\mathcal{S})$$
Thus, if there is a "nice" formula for $g$, then calculating $g(\mathcal{R})=(-1)^{\binom{a}{c}+a+c+1}\binom{a-1}{c-1}$ would prove $(*)$. The hope is that such a proof would translate to a nice counting argument without the language of boolean lattices.

Comment: One way to prove that $\sum_k (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=\delta_{n0}$ is to produce a matching between even and odd subsets of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. For example, given $X\subseteq[n]$, let $f(X)=X\setminus\{n\}$ if $n\in X$, and let $f(X)=X\cup\{n\}$ if $n\notin X$. Then $f$ is an involution for any $n\ge 1$. You can try to deal with the other identity similarly.

Comment: I don't know if you might find useful ideas in the answers to a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3970442/573047) but where the size of subsets is not fixed.